# How can I center my main blog content?

Tags: html, css

Currently my blog is split into two horizontal sections. The main content and a right-hand sidebar.

I'd like to center the main content whilst reducing the width of the sidebar so I can keep it.

How can I do this?

I've tried adding `margin-left:16%` to `.content`but I believe this is the incorrect way to do things.

Demo at: https://www.moneynest.co.uk/how-to-choose-a-broker/

**Note:**
I'm running Wordpress with a custom genesis theme using Bootstrap.

My stripped page code is:

```
<html>
<body class="post-template-default single single-post postid-594 single-format-standard logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support nolayout windows chrome override" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage"><div class="site-container">
<div class="site-inner">    
    <div class="content">
        <div id="container">
            <div class="central-container">
                <div class="middle-content">
                <div class="inner-post-head">
                </div>
                    <div class="data-content">
    <!--MAIN CONTENT HERE -->         
                  </div><!-- End .middle-content -->
    </div>
        </div><!-- End #container -->
  </div><!-- End #content -->
     <aside class="sidebar sidebar-primary widget-area" role="complementary" aria-label="Primary Sidebar" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPSideBar" id="genesis-sidebar-primary"><h2 class="genesis-sidebar-title screen-reader-text">Primary Sidebar</h2><section id="text-9" class="widget widget_text"><div class="widget-wrap">          <div class="textwidget">
 <!--SIDE BAR CONTENT HERE--></div>
  <!--<div id="popular-articles">
    <p class="popular-articles-text">Popular articles</p>
  </div>-->
</div>
</div>
        </div>
<section id="text-10" class="widget widget_text"><div class="widget-wrap"   
        </div></section>
        </div>
        </aside>
<!--END OF SIDEBAR--!>
<!--FOOTER STUFF-->
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I've gone ahead and added my code above. Hope this helps.

I've not added all my classes as this would be unruly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To center the .content div you can simply use:

```
.content{
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

or

```
.content {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

The "auto" statement does the trick. ;)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried adding these but it doesn't seem to work. I've noticed there is two instances of a width being applied to .content. One at 880px and another at 792px. If I remove both of these it still won't center with your suggestions. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the missing bracket is not throwing things off. I added the bracket to the code(indicated in bold)

```
</div>
<section id="text-10" class="widget widget_text"><div class="widget-wrap"**>**   
        </div></section>
        </div>
        </aside>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was just a typo on my part. It exists in the code.